# Is every right coset a subgroup of the group?

Tags: group-theory

Is every right coset a subgroup of the group?

Comment: No. In fact, only one of the cosets contains the identity element.

Answer (score 2):

If $H \leq G$ then $aHbH=abH \quad \forall a,b\in G$ if and only if $H$ is a **normal** subgroup of $G$ i.e $aHa^{-1}=H \quad \forall a\in G$ .
For a counter example $ \langle (1,2)\rangle \leq S_3 $.

Comment: I thought that he,she had asked that when cosets make a group :)

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the other answers with an example: Wikipedia has this neat diagram about cosets.

[image: coset diagram]

It portrays

- the group $G = \mathbb Z_8$ under addition,
- its subgroup $H = \{0, 4\}$,
- all cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Clearly, only $H$ contains the identity element $0$, so only $H$ is a group. The cosets $1+H$ and $2+H$ and $3+H$ don’t contain $0$, so they fail to satisfy this important group property.

Answer (score 1):

No, Let $(G,\circ ,e)$ be our group, Note that for every $g\in G$ and $H\le G$ s.t $g\neq e$, We get that $e\notin gH$ And therefor cannot be a subgroup of $H$ nor $G$ (the same goes for left cosets)